# SceneKit: z value of tap location?

Tags: swift, xcode, scenekit, arkit, skscene

I am using sceneKit in my project, and would like to add a red sphere (as a marker)on the location that the user taps on a 3d model of a human body (see picture below). With the code I have currently, the sphere is added in the correct position - however, it not added on top of the human body, but rather extremely close to the camera (the z value is off). How can change the z value of the red sphere so that it is added on top of the human body rather than in front of the camera? Thank you so much :)

```
  import UIKit
  import QuartzCore
  import SceneKit
      
   class GameViewController: UIViewController {
        
    var selectedNode: SCNNode!
    var markerSphereNode: SCNNode!
    var bodyNode: SCNNode!
    @IBOutlet weak var sceneView: SCNView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/femaleBodySceneKit Scene.scn")
        markerSphereNode = scene?.rootNode.childNode(withName: "markerSphere", recursively: true)
        bodyNode = scene?.rootNode.childNode(withName: "Body_M_GeoRndr", recursively: true)
        
        sceneView.scene = scene
        sceneView.allowsCameraControl = true
        _ = sceneView.pointOfView
    }
    
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let touch = touches.first!
        let touchPoint = touch.location(in: sceneView)
        
        if sceneView.hitTest(touch.location(in: sceneView), options: nil).first != nil {
            markerSphereNode.position = sceneView.unprojectPoint(
                SCNVector3(x: Float(touchPoint.x),
                           y: Float(touchPoint.y),
                           z: 0.56182814))
        }
    }
}
```

how the red sphere appears when you tap on a location in the body
[image: how the red sphere appears when you tap on a location in the body]

how far it is from the body when you rotate the camera (it is in the background if you look closely

[image: how far it is from the body when you rotate the camera (it is in the background if you look closely)]

how the red dot SHOULD appear
[image: how the red dot SHOULD appear]

Answer (score 0):

`SCNHitTestResult` provides you with [`localCoordinates`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnhittestresult/1523032-localcoordinates) and [`worldCoordinates`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnhittestresult/1523058-worldcoordinates) already. There's a need to use the `unprojectPoint` method.